No entries found while installing parcel
I try to install parcel via terminal and it keeps popping the same error "no entries found". enter image description here
Here is my package.json:
enter image description here
I tried "parcel start", but it shows that command is not found.
I used "npm install parcel-bundler", but it showed this:
to look for some similar cases online, but I'm new to this and I don't want to use solutions I don't understand, I would really appriciate any help.
